# Can a JSF Project run without using Servlets?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am new to JSF and I have a question:

As far as I know Servlets are classes that are used to get HTML requests and to provide HTML responses. Such as:

> HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response

But in a typical JSF project, I do not see these classes used at all, instead all I see is managed beans and Facelet pages.

However in web.xml I see:

```
<servlet>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also JSTL.jar's are required to build a JSF Project as far as I understand.

So are these classes

> HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response

still used in a JSF Project? If so how?

Comment: This is outside of the question, but I heavily recommend you to **not use** `/faces/*` as URL mapping, instead use `/.xhtml`. Why? Because the first one will even process resources under the virtual `faces` folder, like images, JS and CSS files, etc and you could have problems when getting unexpected results (lot of people in SO have had similar problems with this approach).

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by process?

Comment: Every resource in a web page turns to be a GET request to the server. You can check this if you press F12 on Chrome/Firefox (with Firebug plugin installed) and go to the Network tab/option, you refresh (or navigate to) a page and see that there will be a GET request with the website URL and then lot of GET request done to to get every resource (image, CSS, JS, etc). This mean, if the `FacesServlet` maps to `/faces/*`, every of these resources will be processed by the `FacesServlet`. Also, you don't need to handle that kind of job to this Servlet.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! What you mean is, keep your statics in some other folder and just get them without using the FacesServlet?

Comment: Actually having JSF handle your resources can have some benefits as it supports internationalization and versioning see http://java.wildstartech.com/Java-Platform-Enterprise-Edition/JavaServer-Faces/javaserver-faces-20/using-the-resource-framework-with-css-style-sheets to get some idea of how this works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have indicated, JSF itself is implemented with important ties to Servlet technology. The Faces Servlet is itself, well, a Servlet.

Do note that the mapping in web.xml that you showed is optional for a JSF 2.1 implementation running on a Java EE 6 (specifically Servlet 3) container. In that case the extensions `.jsf` and `.faces` as well as the path `faces\*` are automatically mapped to the Faces Servlet, and thus to your pages.

JSF itself does try to abstract from Servlet technology. For instance, there's the type [ExternalContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) that abstracts from the "nature of its containing application environment". In practice this means it's compatible with both Servlets and Portlets. But, at least one of those 2 environments is needed with the current versions.

Theoretically someone could port a JSF implementation to a non-Servlet and non-Portlet environment, but to the best of my knowledge nobody has done this yet.

Answer (score 3):

`javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` is used. It is extended by the `FacesServlet` (meaning it is an `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet`). JSF `FacesServlet` loads the view, builds a component tree, processes events, and renders the response.

Answer (score 2):

They are used, since JSF itself is provided by a Servlet named `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet`. That is when someone calls your view they end up calling servlet defined in `javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet`, this servlet then will do all magic JSF stuff that renders your XML page.

Comment: What does int mean, JSF is provided by Servlet?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the JSF implementation it might be possible to run without using Servlets. While the JSF standard requires implementers to provide a Servlet based implementation for portability it allows implementers to support other ways to invoke the JSF lifecycle.
(Stated in Section 11.1.1 of the [standard](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-full-oth-JSpec/))

However I'm not aware that there actually is any implementation that does provide this possibility.